# TSQL - Identify the table name as a column of the single or multiple tables in a select statement WITHOUT HARDCODING it as part of the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to display the table name in my select statement.

```
select col1, table_name_1 as table_name  from table_name_1
```

Which I insert into another table.

My problem is I have to do this dynamically not as explained by this question.

[Display the table name in the select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321131/display-the-table-name-in-the-select-statement)

Not sure if this available with a single key word like for an eg. the currentdate we could use something like GETDATE().

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: To do it dynamically implies that the actual select query is dynamically generated. Therefore, you would add the name of the table as a column in addition to adding it to the FROM clause. No - there is no "keyword" or tsql function that will do this for you.

Comment: Obviously, this is not a built-in capability because queries can refer to multiple tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you were told already, there is no special keyword, which you could use for an *easy-cheesy* solution. If you really need this, you would add the table's name as a parameter and use a dynamically created statement.

Another approach was a VIEW for each table you are looking for, something along this

```
CREATE VIEW Table1_withName AS
SELECT 'Table1' AS TableName, * FROM Table1 --use columns instead of "*"
```

You can use this VIEW instead of the table in all your selects. This is not *without hardcoding*, but you could even generate the code to create your views out of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`. And when you call the views, there is no special action needed.

### You might use `FOR XML AUTO`...

There is a **fully generic / ad-hoc approach** too, but I doubt that this will help you:

Hint: I use - as example only - a `TOP 3 * FROM sys.objects`. This would work with your tables too.

--`FOR XML AUTO` will add the table's name as the element's name

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM sys.objects FOR XML AUTO
--result
<sys.objects name="sysrscols" object_id="3" ...
```

--In case you use an alias, this alias is used

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM sys.objects AnyAlias FOR XML AUTO
```

--You would have to change this a little, if you want to enforce to include NULL values.
--But this is *element centric* XML now, the one before was *attribute centric*.

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM sys.objects FOR XML AUTO,ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

--This is the way you could use this, to simulate the *generic table's name*

```
SELECT EachRow.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS TableName
      ,EachRow.value('./@name,','nvarchar(max)') AS name
      ,EachRow.value('./@object_id','int') AS object_id
      ,EachRow.value('./@schema_id','int') AS schema_id
      --add all columns here 
FROM
(
    --Your original Statement goes here
    SELECT TOP 3 * FROM sys.objects 
    FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
) A(TheSelectAsXml)
CROSS APPLY A.TheSelectAsXml.nodes('*') B(EachRow);
```

The result

```
TableName       name        object_id   schema_id
sys.objects     sysrscols   3           4
```

This would even work with joined sources. Try this one out:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM sys.objects 
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns ON sys.objects.object_id=sys.all_columns.object_id
FOR XML AUTO,TYPE
```

Comment: Thank you Shnugo. Of the two answers I got I  have to select your one as the answer in this occasion because the views can be built dynamically using the sys tables and use a single column in any of the tables as part of a select statement to identify the table you are dealing with. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is inbuilt function available in T-SQL other than `OBJECT_NAME (object_id('TableName'))` which required to hard-code Table name.

However, as workaround, following query could fulfill your requirements:

```
Declare @tbname varchar(50); 
Declare @SelectQuery varchar(2000); 

set @tbname = 'YourTable';
set @SelectQuery = 'select *, OBJECT_NAME (object_id(' + '''' + @tbname + '''' +')) from ' + @tbname;
--print @SelectQuery;
exec (@SelectQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks Shekar, any possibility to make this the default value for a table column that would hold the table name, via a function or a stored procedure?

Comment: @user11969677, Yes you can create scalar function with `OBJECT_NAME (object_id('TableName'))`, but that would NOT serve your requirement - "without hard-coding". Do you have any difficulties using Dynamic SQL method (as mentioned in answer)?